# Insert in postgres jsonb array causes the json escaping key and value - golang pq

Tags: postgresql, go, jsonb, pq

I am marshalling the data as

```
b, err := json.MarshalJSON(&u3)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error:", err)
    }
```

and then insert

```
INSERT INTO user_list (userid, listtype, data) VALUES ($1, $2, (array[$3::json]))
```

The data is written as

> {"{\"from\": \"2010-11-12\", \"till\": \"2018-3-10\", \"oieId\":
>   \"1212458454\", \"iType\": \"ird\"}"}

Nothing is helping me prevent those escaping from being written even though the data type is json.RawMessage.

Is there a way to just write as JSON and not cast the $3 to be cast to JSON or just prevent those escapes from being written to jsonb[] type row ?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: why you are implementing `MarshalJSON` rahter than `Marshal`.

Comment: Could you show the code that makes the insert statement and the code that you use to read out the value?

Comment: Also used json.Marshal, but MarshalJSON returns the JSON encoding, which I thought might solve. _, err = db.Exec(sqlStatement, u1, u2, u3). sqlStatement is the insert statement posted above.

Comment: I am viewing the result in DB using psql.

Comment: @Walker *"The data is written as ..."* Not really, that's how the data is displayed by psql not how it's written. Escaped double quotes of keys and string values constitute invalid json and you would not be able to insert such values into a column of type jsonb or jsonb[].

Comment: @Walker try selecting the element from the array, you'll see that outside of the array the json is not escaped (e.g. `SELECT data[1] FROM user_list ...`). And then try inserting, through psql, a json value with it's double quotes escaped, see if that goes through (e.g. `INSERT INTO user_list (data) VALUES (array['{\"foo\":\"bar\"}'::jsonb])`).